# Month to int in Go

Tags: go

**Situation:**

When I call time functions like `Second()`, `Year()` etc., I get a result of tye `int`. But when I call `Month()`, I get a result of type `Month`.

I found the following in the online docs:

```
type Month int
...
func (m Month) String() string
```

.. but I don't quite understand it.

**Problem:**

My code has the following error because `m` is *not* an `int`:

> invalid operation: `m / time.Month(10) + offset` (mismatched types time.Month and int)

**Question:**

How to get an `int` from `Month()`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Considering:

```
var m time.Month
```

`m`'s type *underlying* type is `int`, so it can be [converted](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to `int`:

```
var i int = int(m) // normally written as 'i := int(m)'
```

On a side note: The question shows a division '`m / time.Month(10)`'. That may be a bug unless you want to compute some *dekamonth* value ;-)

Comment: ThX,the code i wrote is byte(m/10 + offset) but the tool "smartly" display m / time.Month(10) in the error log.

Answer (score 22):

You have to explicitly convert it to an int:

```
var m Month = ...
var i int = int(m)
```

Check this [minimal example](http://play.golang.org/p/S6CMn-VNY7) in the go playground.

Comment: It's really conversion and not type casting.

Answer (score 7):

Technically this is not int but if you are trying to get string with month like `"2020-04-16"` (April 16,2020), you can do this:

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Printf("%d-%02d-%02d", t.Year(), int(t.Month()), t.Day())
```